# Server can not connect to any port outside

Tags: windows-server-2008

i have search every where in forums and have no helpful topic. Please help me.
Last night, my server suddenly can not connect to any port to another server.
I had checked SQL, HDD free space, Application, event viewer, service not running, but i found no thing.
I restarted server and it worked again like a charm.
Then i compare log of services running after restart (server ok) and before restart (server failed), no thing special except some services after restart not started.
I also tried to disable, enable network card, but useless.

Do anyone help me to find what caused server to that status? I happened 2 times.

My server : Windows Server 2008

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of tips to get you started troubleshooting:

When the sudden distruption of network connectivity happens next time, have a look at your network settings at that time. Do a "ipconfig /all" in command prompt, and save that output to a text file. Compare it to output when network connectivity works. See if your server has lost it's IP address for example.

Try pinging your default gateway. If you don't know what it is, do "ipconfig" and have a look at "Default gateway" line in the network interface you should be using. Then do "ping " and see if it works. Note that not all IP-addresses necessary respond to pings, but see if your gateway responds when everything is working and if it's responding when network is down. If pinging interrupts also, then it's a sure reason why everything else also fails.

Try using another network interface card in your server. Maybe it's a hardware problem. When using the same network switch and cable, is any other machine having same kind of problems? Try isolating one variable at a time.

Comment: Dear Taskinen, no thing special about network. I still ping to another server, gateway, client.... just cannot connect to port outside (for some software, task,..). It's so weird because another server or PC Client form same subnet or difference subnet still connect any port to that server but the other way (from that server to outside) can not be done. It's happend again today. 3 times in 3 months. Please help me.